# Difficulty in handling 404 with OData Web Api to send custom response

Tags: c#, routes, asp.net-web-api2, odata, owin

I have web api 2.2 which is owin hosted serving odata v4 endpoints.

Consider i have defined two actions like this:

```
public class EntityController : ODataController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("A")]
    public IHttpActionResult Action1()
    {
        //some code
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [ODataRoute("B")]
    public IHttpActionResult Action2()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

I have defined the routes using:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.MapODataServiceRoute
(
   routeName: "ODataRoute",
   routePrefix: "Data",
   model: GetModel()
);
```

I query using `http://<host>:<port>/Data/A` and `http://<host>:<port>/Data/B`. Everything is working fine.

Now, wheni query `http://<host>:<port>/Data/C`, it gives me 404 which is expected. I want to return data like `Resource not found for the segment 'C'`.

I tried implementing ExceptionHandler but the Hanlde method was not getting hit. I had registered the Handler like this:

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new CustomExceptionHandler());
```

Any suggestions on how i can implement it? Thanks in advance.